# log4j logger statements are not displayed in jboss wildfly AS

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, log4j, wildfly-8

I have added log4j.properties and included relevant log 4j entries in pom.xml in spring mvc web application. But , the logger statements are displayed neither in the eclipse ( which is configured with jboss wildfly AS ) console or server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **removed** the **log4j.properties** file from the web application & surprisingly see JBoss WildFly AS takes care of printing the logger statements in the eclipse  console as well as server log.